# MySQL-query returns empty results adding a valid condition (only in script, not in phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, conditional-statements

Ok, I have the following code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE p_id=$this->p_id AND pn_id=$this->pn_id AND vg_id=$this->vg_id";
$dump=$this->_db->query($sql);
if (PEAR::isError($dump)) die($dump->getMessage());
while ($data = $dump->fetchRow(DB_FETCHMODE_OBJECT)) {
print_r($data);
}
```

If I echo $sql and execute it in phpmyadmin, all is fine. Unfortunally in this script, it returns NULL. A curious issue is, that if I remove the condition 'p_id=$this->p_id' like:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pn_id=$this->pn_id AND vg_id=$this->vg_id";
```

all is fine in phpmyadmin AND the script. So, I can assume that the db-connection is ok, the query is ok, all is ok. Adding the condition 'p_id=$this->p_id' again results NULL in the script and works fine in phpmyadmin and shows the expectable result.

Any ideas how to fix this strange drop?

**EDIT:**

When I echo $dump, it fires the following error message:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class DB_result could not be converted to string
```

$dump should be a resource but it isn't...?!?

**NEXT EDIT:**

When I echo $sql and paste the static query to the script, all works fine:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE p_id=1 AND pn_id=2 AND vg_id=3";
```

Now I replace only 'p_id=1' with 'p_id={$this->p_id}' ... nothing, empty, no results. Replacing 'pn_id=2' with 'pn_id={$this->pn_id}' and 'vg_id=3' with 'vg_id={$this->vg_id}', it works fine... All values are integer and set >0, no strings. This makes me mad...!

Answer (score 0):

`$this->pn_id` needs to be `'{$this->pn_id}'`. You have to use curly braces and don't forget your quotes if that's a String. Maybe foolishly, but I'm also assuming that you are using `$this` inside of a `class`. `public $pn_id;` also has to have an initial value. In the case that it's `public` you can assign a value, after calling a `new` instance of your `class`, before running whatever method your code above should be inside.